# Load all images from folder

Tags: javascript, php, image, directory, image-gallery

I'm trying to insert images from a folder into a gallery made in javascript.

I'm using a php cycle to insert all the images but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
<div id="mygallery">
            <?php $directory="img/portfolio";
            $images=glob($directory . "*.jpg");
            $swipebox = "swipebox";
            foreach($images as $image) {
                echo "<a href=" .$image." class=".$swipebox."> <img alt=" . $directory . "src=". $image . "/>";
            }?></div>
```

Comment: try this $images=glob($directory.'/*');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
<div id="mygallery">
<?php
    $directory="img/portfolio/";
    $images=glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    $swipebox = "swipebox";
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo "<a href=" .$image." class=".$swipebox."> <img alt=" . $directory . " src=". $image . " /></a>";
    }
?>
</div>
```

Here are the mistake that you have done in your code:
1. Need to put slash '/' at after line no 3 after the image directory path
2. Need to put space between `src` and `alt` attribute at line no 7

Answer (score 0):

This is working, you needed a space before "src" and close the href.

```
<?php 
    $directory="img/portfolio";
    $images=glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    $swipebox = "swipebox";
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo " <a href=" .$image." class=".$swipebox."> <img alt=" . $directory . " src='". $image . "' /> </a>";
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
<?php
    $allImageFiles = scandir('img/portfolio');
    $swipebox = "swipebox";


    foreach($allImageFiles as $key=>$image) {
        echo "<a href=" .$image." class=".$swipebox."> <img alt=" . $directory . "src=". $image . "/>";

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above comments have mentioned two things.
1. Add slash (/) in path
2. Add Space between src and alt.

The list retuned by glob function is filenames/directory names matching given pattern. you have to join path in image source. Try below code. It should work.

```
<div id="mygallery">
<?php
    $directory="img/portfolio/";
    $images=glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    $swipebox = "swipebox";
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo "<a href=" .$image." class=".$swipebox."> <img alt=" . $directory . " src=". $directory .$image . " /></a>";
    }
?>
</div>
```